# POST Command of ADT RestAPI returns "HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed Allow: DELETE,GET,PATCH,PUT Content-Length:0"

Tags: azure-digital-twins

When I followed MS Learn course of ADT, and
I tried to call ADT's REST API (POST), ADT service return 405 ERROR...

----Command---

`curl -i --location --request POST 'https://{yourAdtName}.api.eus.digitaltwins.azure.net/digitaltwins/query?api-version=2020-10-31' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer {Your-Bearer-Token}' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Message-Id: 12345' \ --data-raw '{ "query": "SELECT * FROM DIGITALTWINS" }'`

ADT Response:

Allow: DELETE,GET,PATCH,PUT
Content-Length: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
traceresponse: 00-2f53a2a2df5294428cedd1bdc023596d-fea71b423e62224b-01
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 00:17:04 GMT

Answer (score 1):

The API for querying is /query instead of /digitaltwins/query If you change your URL to
`https://{yourAdtName}.api.eus.digitaltwins.azure.net/query?api-version=2020-10-31`

Then you should be good to go!